# Explanations in nested align equations with aligned

Tags: align, amsmath, tags

I am trying to put some explanations in a nested align environment. I am using aligned for the nested equations, and I want to use `\tag{}` for the explanations. Unfortunately, tag is not allowed in `aligned`. Is there an alternative for this? I don't want to use `witharrows`, I just want an explanation on the right side.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  &f(x)=x^2-x-1\tag{explanation}\\
  &g(x)=\frac{1}{2}-x\\
  &\begin{aligned}
   (f\circ g)(x)
      &=f(g(x))=f\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}-x\Bigr)
       =\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}-x\Bigr)^2-\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}-x\Bigr)-1\\
      &= \frac{1}{4}-x+x^2-\frac{1}{2}+x-1 \tag{some explanation}
   \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

What I get is an error `Package amsmath: \tag not allowed here`, and the pdf looks like this:
[image]

I.e. there is no (some explanation) in the last line. Grateful for any help.

Comment: This is very weird markup, you have no alignment at all in the outer `align`  why not align on the = (and the no nesting is needed)

Comment: This is not what `\tag` is for. It is used to give a custom cross referencing label to the equation, not to just typeset some comments. Use `\text` for that. (Though any explanation longer than a few words should probably not be in the math environment at all.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, fair point, I just wanted to make the example as simple as possible, in my actual setup I have a more complicated equation with a lot of macros.

Comment: @schtandard I just tried this, but it does not left align. How would I be able to have an outer explanation left align with an explanation that is inside the nested environment? And I just want to put one or two words as explanation.

Comment: Alignment is dictated by the usual rules of `align` (or `aligned`). Try providing an example that actually shows the alignment you need to achieve, as it is hard to guess at you application from what you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `alignat` environment the desired output can be seen with

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  f(x) &=x^2-x-1   && \text{explanation} \\
  g(x) &=\frac{1}{2}-x \\
  (f\circ g)(x) &=f(g(x))=f\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}-x\Bigr)
       =\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}-x\Bigr)^2-\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}-x\Bigr)-1\\
      &= \frac{1}{4}-x+x^2-\frac{1}{2}+x-1  && \text{some explanation}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

which gives the result

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Is it at all possible to align the explanations on the right, though?